# Label and unordered list within container with list positioned absolutely and enclosed in single border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a filter dropdown where only the label of the dropdown will be visible initially, and then on click of the label, the list of options will drop down over the top of the rest of the content(using `absolute` positioning). The part I am struggling with is enclosing both the `relative` positioned span and the absolute positioned list within a container so that both are within a border and the border expands as the absolutely positioned menu slides down. Below is what I've tried, as you can see it's a little wonky(content jumping around) and the borders don't line up quite right. Not sure if this is the right approach, open to ideas on how to improve the look/functionality:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width:400px;
}
  .dropdown {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
    .dropdown.open {
      border-bottom:none;
    }
    .dropdown span {
      display:block;
      padding:10px 15px;
    }
    .dropdown ul {
      display:block;
      background:#fff;
      width:100%;
      list-style-type:none;
      padding:0 0 15px;
      margin:0;
      border:1px solid black;
      border-top:none;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:10;
      display:none;
    }
      .dropdown ul > li {
        padding:15px 15px 0;
      }
        .dropdown ul > li:first-child {
          padding-top:0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Label</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
      <li>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel tellus sit amet diam sagittis tempor. Nullam sed nunc non ipsum rhoncus tincidunt. Ut odio nisi, convallis et augue vitae, dictum semper mauris. Donec ullamcorper vehicula mi in interdum. Cras at hendrerit dolor, a scelerisque arcu. Nullam sagittis consectetur hendrerit. Donec interdum gravida tincidunt. Morbi id sem eleifend, gravida urna sit amet, vestibulum nibh. Pellentesque non convallis massa. Vivamus non metus lobortis, condimentum lorem vitae, semper augue. Ut eget ante eget orci elementum sodales. Donec nec ligula mauris.</p>

<p>Nunc a consectetur nulla, vel viverra velit. Maecenas sagittis velit turpis, eu dapibus turpis blandit vitae. Duis mollis, lorem ac consectetur hendrerit, turpis odio lacinia eros, sed lacinia velit justo in est. Integer non mauris lacinia, sagittis justo sed, accumsan tortor. Suspendisse a commodo tortor. Etiam tincidunt mi sit amet elementum fringilla. Pellentesque luctus ac leo non lobortis. Morbi iaculis consequat lacus eget tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus ultrices congue augue, vel consequat velit viverra sed. Sed a finibus velit. Mauris sed orci lectus. Vivamus bibendum ante et quam volutpat, sed venenatis mi dignissim. Ut tempus iaculis faucibus.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done so far. The only missing details are:

- a `margin-left: -1px;` on the `<ul>` which will make it shift to the left by `1px`
- a `border: 1px solid transparent` on `.dropdown.open`, to prevent the rest of the page shifting up by `1px`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });
  $(window).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').is('.dropdown')
      || $(e.target).closest('li').is('.dropdown li')
    ) {
      $('.dropdown.open span').trigger('click')
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dropdown.open {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.dropdown ul {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.dropdown ul>li {
  padding: 15px 15px 0;
}

.dropdown ul>li:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.dropdown.open {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Label</span>
      <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="body-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel tellus sit amet diam sagittis tempor. Nullam sed nunc non ipsum rhoncus tincidunt. Ut odio nisi, convallis et augue vitae, dictum semper mauris. Donec ullamcorper vehicula mi in interdum.
      Cras at hendrerit dolor, a scelerisque arcu. Nullam sagittis consectetur hendrerit. Donec interdum gravida tincidunt. Morbi id sem eleifend, gravida urna sit amet, vestibulum nibh. Pellentesque non convallis massa. Vivamus non metus lobortis, condimentum
      lorem vitae, semper augue. Ut eget ante eget orci elementum sodales. Donec nec ligula mauris.</p>

    <p>Nunc a consectetur nulla, vel viverra velit. Maecenas sagittis velit turpis, eu dapibus turpis blandit vitae. Duis mollis, lorem ac consectetur hendrerit, turpis odio lacinia eros, sed lacinia velit justo in est. Integer non mauris lacinia, sagittis
      justo sed, accumsan tortor. Suspendisse a commodo tortor. Etiam tincidunt mi sit amet elementum fringilla. Pellentesque luctus ac leo non lobortis. Morbi iaculis consequat lacus eget tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus
      et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus ultrices congue augue, vel consequat velit viverra sed. Sed a finibus velit. Mauris sed orci lectus. Vivamus bibendum ante et quam volutpat, sed venenatis mi dignissim. Ut tempus iaculis faucibus.</p>
  </div>
```

*Note:* I also took the liberty of adding a small closing function to your JavaScript, for when clicking outside `.dropdown` or on one of its options, as yours only closes when clicked on label.

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of changes get it to work. I added `box-sizing:border-box` to all elements, just so I know we are dealing with consistent widths with borders. Notice how the borders of the absolute positioned items were both on the inside of the parent border. If you add the width of the border to the width of the children, your borders line up in terms of how far apart they are `width: calc(100% + 2px)` and you just need to offset the absolute positioning to `left: -1px`. Different browsers may give you fits with a negative value here, so you could use `transform: translateX(-1px)` instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.container {
  width:400px;
}
  .dropdown {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
  }
    .dropdown.open {
      border-bottom:none;
    }
    .dropdown span {
      display:block;
      padding:10px 15px;
    }
    .dropdown ul {
      display:block;
      background:#fff;
      width: calc(100% + 2px);
      list-style-type:none;
      padding:0 0 15px;
      margin:0;
      border:1px solid black;
      border-top:none;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:10;
      display:none;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-1px);
      transform: translateX(-1px);
    }
      .dropdown ul > li {
        padding:15px 15px 0;
width: 100%;
      }
        .dropdown ul > li:first-child {
          padding-top:0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Label</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
      <li>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel tellus sit amet diam sagittis tempor. Nullam sed nunc non ipsum rhoncus tincidunt. Ut odio nisi, convallis et augue vitae, dictum semper mauris. Donec ullamcorper vehicula mi in interdum. Cras at hendrerit dolor, a scelerisque arcu. Nullam sagittis consectetur hendrerit. Donec interdum gravida tincidunt. Morbi id sem eleifend, gravida urna sit amet, vestibulum nibh. Pellentesque non convallis massa. Vivamus non metus lobortis, condimentum lorem vitae, semper augue. Ut eget ante eget orci elementum sodales. Donec nec ligula mauris.</p>

<p>Nunc a consectetur nulla, vel viverra velit. Maecenas sagittis velit turpis, eu dapibus turpis blandit vitae. Duis mollis, lorem ac consectetur hendrerit, turpis odio lacinia eros, sed lacinia velit justo in est. Integer non mauris lacinia, sagittis justo sed, accumsan tortor. Suspendisse a commodo tortor. Etiam tincidunt mi sit amet elementum fringilla. Pellentesque luctus ac leo non lobortis. Morbi iaculis consequat lacus eget tristique. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus ultrices congue augue, vel consequat velit viverra sed. Sed a finibus velit. Mauris sed orci lectus. Vivamus bibendum ante et quam volutpat, sed venenatis mi dignissim. Ut tempus iaculis faucibus.</p>
</div>
```